# Выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу перечисления без области видимости

Tags: c++

Нужно переписать задачу b[i,j] = 45**[45**{(9i+j) mod 256} mod 257] mod 257, но компилятор выдает ошибку и подчеркивает строки с int a и int b.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            int c = (9*j + i) % 256;
            int b = pow(45, c) % 257;
            int a = (pow(45, b)) % 257;

            std::cout << a << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну все верно, `pow` возвращает `double`, к нему операция `%` неприменима...

Comment: Как тогда правильно написать?

Comment: Написать функцию целочисленного возведения в степень по модулю (иначе будет переполнение)